# Unrecognized command line in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I compiled the following program but I don't know why am I getting the following error:

> error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’.

My gcc version is 4.6 and I have set c++ compiler in netbeans to c++11.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void parallel_sort(T* data, int len, int grainsize)
{
    if(len < grainsize) // Use grainsize instead of thread count so that we don't e.g. spawn 4 threads just to sort 8 elements.
    {
        std::sort(data, data + len, std::less<T>());
    }
    else
    {
        parallel_sort(data + len/2, len/2, grainsize); // No need to spawn another thread just to block the calling thread which would do nothing.

        std::inplace_merge(data, data + len/2, data + len, std::less<T>());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `-std=c++0x`, gcc4.6 is probably too old to support `-std=c++11`

Comment: I believe 4.7.1 or so added it.

Comment: @chris, [4.7.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Standards.html)

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Cool, thanks. I think that puts it one minor version over what I'm using for class next term (two, actually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading the manual for GCC 4.6, which says you need to use `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Standards.html

This is because GCC 4.6 was released before the C++11 standard was published.

You will need to adjust your Netbeans settings to use `-std=c++0x` instead of `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your GCC to something that supports modern C++11, like GCC 4.8 or greater.